# Arrow operator for array length? No output when printed, How?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this code to iterate over an array, instead of using `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)` I used an arrow operator (I don't understand really well how it works).

I don't understand why when I print out `array->length()` it is just a blank output, and how can the for loop work and terminate properly with the set condition of `i < array->length()`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string cars[] = {"Corvette", "Ford", "Mustang"};

    cars[1] = "Camaro", "Ford";
    for (int i = 0; i < cars->length(); i++)
    {
        cout << cars[i] << '\n';
    }

    cout << cars->length();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cars->length()` is actually `cars[0].length()`.

Comment: Arrays are dumb as <expletive deleted> and predate C++ by decades. They have no member functions. Use them sparingly and prefer `std::array` when you know the size at compile time and `std::vector` when you don't.

Comment: `cars[1] = "Camaro", "Ford";` probably also doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @Peter thank you, for ```cars[1] = "Camaro", "Ford";``` i was just trying to see what it does (just sets car[1] to Camaro), but does the compiler just ignores the second string? Or something else is going on?

Comment: Semantically, there is more going on, but - yes - `cars[1] = "Camaro", "Ford"` has the same *net observable effect* as `cars[1] = "Camaro"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `cars->length()`, the array `std::string cars[3]` decays into a pointer to the first element. Using `->` on that pointer dereferences it, and calling `length()` on that first element will return the length of the element (8 for "Corvette") - not the size of the array.

Since your loop is equivalent to:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```

and you dereference `cars[i]` inside the loop, you access the array out of bounds. The array only has 3 elements. This causes *undefined behavior*, and your program could do just about anything - or nothing, or crash.

Another problem in this program is this use of the comma operator:

```cpp
cars[1] = "Camaro", "Ford";
```

This assigns `"Camaro"` to `cars[1]`, but the result of the full expression is `"Ford"`. Example:

```cpp
auto x = (cars[1] = "Camaro", "Ford");
```

`x` is now `"Ford"` while `cars[1]` is `"Camaro"`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i understood what you say; do you know why when i print it ```cout << cars->length();``` it just returns a blank line? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChristianCangelli You access the array out of bounds. The array has 3 elements, but you try to access 8. The program most likely crashes because undefined behavior. Also, always add a newline: `cout << cars->length() << '\n';`

Comment: @ChristianCangelli Do you find the answer acceptable as is, or do you want me to clarify anything further?

Answer (score 5):

@TedLyngmo has already covered the problems here, and why the code doesn't work as well as it might appear to.

I'll try to cover some of the ways to make the code work. The preferred one is probably a range-based for loop, like this:

```cpp
    for (auto const &car : cars)
    {
        cout << car << '\n';
    }
```

Another alternative to using `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` is something like this:

```cpp
template <class T, size_t N>
size_t length(T (&array)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

With this, you can do something more like your original code:

```cpp
for (int i=0; i<length(cars); i++) {
    std::cout << cars[i] << '\n';
}
```

The big advantage of this compared to `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` is that if you have a pointer instead of an actual array, the `sizeof` code will produce incorrect results, but this simply won't compile at all. You generally don't want to actually define this yourself though--the standard library provides an `std::size` that will do the job for you, without having to remember the syntax for passing an array by reference.

I'd be remiss if I failed to mention that the generally preferred way would be to use an `std::vector` though:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> cars = {"Corvette", "Ford", "Mustang"};
```

With this, you can use the range-based for loop (the first one I showed above) or a `cars.length()`--which will now work correctly, because `cars` is a vector, which has a `length()` member that returns the number of elements in the vector.